# Using variables/expressions in comments (in Thymeleaf template)

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I need to add some information about generation in page.

```
</html>
<!-- page [[${pageCode}]] was generated at [[${#dates.format(currentDate, ‘dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm’)}]]  -->
```

But for me it don't work. 
Should I configure something or do it in another way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the first sample below.

---

**Template markup 1**

```
<span th:inline="text" th:remove="tag" >
   <!-- page [[${pageCode}]] was generated at [[${#dates.format(currentDate, ‘dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm’)}]]  -->
</span>
```

**Result 1**
`<!-- page [[${pageCode}]] was generated at [[${#dates.format(currentDate, ‘dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm’)}]]  -->`

---

**Template markup 2**

```
<span th:text="inline" th:remove="tag" >
   <!-- page [[${pageCode}]] was generated at [[${#dates.format(currentDate, ‘dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm’)}]]  -->
</span>
```

**Result 2** `inline`

Comment: So I know this is an old answer, but according to the documentation

"Standard HTML/XML comments <!-- ... --> can be used anywhere in thymeleaf templates. Anything inside these comments won’t be processed by neither Thymeleaf nor the browser, and will be just copied verbatim to the result:"

To me this reads that Thymeleaf variables won't be processed in the comments. My testing shows that Thymeleaf processes nothing inside HTML comments

Comment: @TJDownes: I cannot confirm that Thymeleaf won't process the variables within comments - works nicely for me. This was exactly the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the example at the top doesn't work - it literally renders the output with the variable names, because Thymeleaf doesn't process inside the HTML comment tags.

The way to do it is to use the th:utext tag and render the comment directly inside that.  It's not ideal and would be good if Thymeleaf had a property to say process inside comments, or the like in future, but there we go.

Here's a working example:

```
<span th:utext="${'<!-- Branch/Firm: ' + branch.id + '/' + branch.firmId + '-->'}" th:remove="tag"></span>
```

If you use `&lt;` and `&gt;` then you get exactly that in the rendered HTML, which the browser will try to render, rather than treat as a comment.

Per the comments below, it appears that this solution works in the Layout dialect, but potentially not in others.

Comment: Is that really working for you? I get `The value of attribute "th:utext" associated with an element type "span" must not contain the '<' character.`

Comment: Yes it is; I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.6, which has Thymeleaf 2.1.4 - it's possible it doesn't work in earlier versions?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.7 with Thymeleaf 2.1.4 and it's not accepting the `<` character inside the `th:utext`.

Comment: Are you wrapping it in the ${''} syntax?  The error message suggests it's directly inside, e.g. you've got something like:

`<span th:utext="<!-- Branch/Firm: ${' branch.id'} -->" th:remove="tag"></span>`

which I think wouldn't work?

Comment: Yes I'm wrapping it.

Works fine: `<span th:utext="${'&lt;!-- Branch/Firm: --&gt;'}" th:remove="tag"></span>`. Broken: `<span th:utext="${'<!-- Branch/Firm: -->'}" th:remove="tag"></span>`

Comment: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#comparators-and-equality

Does agree with you - but it absolutely works for me!  

The only other thing I can think is the page type - I'm using the following header (so it's not XML): `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorator="template">`

Comment: That's the difference. I'm not using the layout dialect.

Comment: Ah ha, OK, well it works in layout then, apparently not in standard Thymeleaf.  Not sure why that would be!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the atribute

```
th:text="inline"
```

in one of the ancestor as you can see in the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#inlining)

In your example, your comment is out of the html root element. You can do this:

```
</html>
<span th:text="inline">
   <!-- page [[${pageCode}]] was generated at [[${#dates.format(currentDate, ‘dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm’)}]]  -->
</span>
```

Hope it can help

Comment: but in this case I receive span tag after closed html tag ?

Comment: should it be th:inline="text" ? such as th:text="inline" produce exception. Anyways 1) It doesn't process comments, 2) I receive <span>  block after html block

Comment: Yeah sorry, add the attribute th:remove="tag" in the span, it will remove the span tag and keeping the comment inside.

Answer (score 1):

The following allowed me to evaluate expressions inside a comment tag

```
<span th:utext="'&lt;!-- ' +  ${pageCode} + ' was generated at ' + ${#dates.format(currentDate, ‘dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm’)} + ' --&gt;'" th:remove="tag"></span>
```

It removes the <span> tag at the end, leaving only the comment

Comment: Or use `th:block` instead of `span th:remove='tag'`:

`<th:block th:utext="'&lt;!-- ' +  ${pageCode} + ' was generated at ' + ${#dates.format(currentDate, ‘dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm’)} + ' --&gt;'"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we didn't found a way how to do it without adding new tag(but it is not applicable).
Just to share: So we used workaround: process page in String and after that concatenate that comment block.

instead

```
templateEngine.process(templateUrl, context, writer);
```

Something like:

```
String htmlCode = templateEngine.process(templateUrl, context);
String comment = String.format("<!-- page %s was generated at %s -->", pageCode, date);
return htmlCode + comment;
```

Comment: actually this is not answer on question, so it can not be accepted answer.