# Evaluating variables in HTML-commented code

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to print my errors, but I don't want them to be printed directly on the page. I'd rather put the errors only in comments.
I have a controller to redirect to the corresponding web page :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean(name = "simpleMappingExceptionResolver")
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver createSimpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver r = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        //mappings.setProperty("ClassNotFoundException", "classNotFound");
        //mappings.setProperty("SQLException", "sqlException");
        //mappings.setProperty("IOException", "ioException");

        r.setExceptionMappings(mappings); // None by default
        r.setDefaultErrorView("error"); // No default
        r.setExceptionAttribute("ex"); // Default is "exception"
        r.setWarnLogCategory("example.MvcLogger"); // No default
        return r;
    }
```

Then I want to do something like this in error.html :

```
<!-- 
    <div th:text="${ex}"/>
-->
```

But I can't find anything working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444322/using-variables-expressions-in-comments-in-thymeleaf-template